# Is it possible to make an autotyping hint text in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

I am trying to add an animation on my editText hint.I saw it on one of the websites. There is a simple search EditText in the website, but its hint types automatically . What i mean, when user loads website, hintext appears letter by letter as we type on keyboard and it never stops. Is it possible to make such an animation in Android too?

Answer (score 0):

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    int count = 0;
    String hint = "hint"
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() { 
            if (count < hint.length){
                editText.setHint(hint.subString(0,count));
                count++;
                handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
            }
        } 
    }; 
    handler.post(runnable);
```

This may or may not work as is.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it did not work